# Move data from key to value in Python dictionary

Tags: python

I have a python dict:

```
{'John': 23, 'Matthew': 8, 'Peter': 45}
```

I want to create a D3 pie chart and need to move my data from the keys so that I can access the values. So I want to end up with:

```
[
  {name: 'John', age: 23},
  {name: 'Matthew', age: 8},
  {name: 'Peter', age: 45}
]
```

How can I do this dynamically (given that I may not know what the current key is, eg. 'John')?

Comment: That's **not** a python list. Also, should the output have `name: 'John'` or `'name': 'John'`? Because the first one is impossible to achieve since `name` would be an identifier and you either get a `NameError` or the key becomes its value. The latter is trivial `[{'name':key, 'age':value} for key,value in data.items()]`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "may not know what the current key is"

Comment: What I mean by not knowing the key is I didn't want a solution that needed to refer to the current key, for eg dict['John'].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = [{"name": key, "age": value} for key, value in my_dict.items()]
```

An example:

```
>>> my_dict = {'John': 23, 'Matthew': 8, 'Peter': 45}
>>> data = [{"name": key, "age": value} for key, value in my_dict.items()]
>>> data
[{'age': 8, 'name': 'Matthew'}, {'age': 23, 'name': 'John'}, {'age': 45, 'name': 'Peter'}]
```

If you are trying to create a javascript friendly representation of the data, then you will need to convert the list of dictionaries to json.